# Run server’s configuration while SSH into one host

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a server that hosts multiple domains:

- server FQDN: `server.provider.com`
- host 1 FQDN: `example.com`
- host 2 FQDN: `example.it`
- host 3 FQDN: `example.es`

I like to use FQDN to connect, I don’t want to use nicknames.

When I connect directly to `server.provider.com` a tunnel is made from my port 3315 to server's 3306 port.

I want this tunnel to be opened every time I SSH into one host (for example when I do `ssh example.com`)

Here is my actual SSH config:

```
Host server.provider.com
  LocalForward 3315 localhost:3306  
Host example.com
  User user1
Host example.it
  User user2
Host example.es
  User user3
```

I've tried this, but is not working:

```
Host server.provider.com
  LocalForward 3315 localhost:3306  
Host example.com
  HostName server.provider.com
  User user1
Host example.it
  HostName server.provider.com
  User user2
Host example.es
  HostName server.provider.com
  User user3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach:

```
Host server.provider.com
  LocalForward 3315 localhost:3306

Host example.com
  User user1
  LocalForward 3315 localhost:3306

Host example.it
  User user2
  LocalForward 3315 localhost:3306

Host example.es
  User user3
  LocalForward 3315 localhost:3306
```

You can group multiple names:

```
Host server.provider.com example.com example.it example.es
  LocalForward 3315 localhost:3306

Host example.com
  User user1

Host example.it
  User user2

Host example.es
  User user3
```

And to make your 2nd example work, you can use the `Match final` feature (new in OpenSSH **8.0**) which enables two-pass parsing of the config file:

```
Match final host server.provider.com
  LocalForward 3315 localhost:3306

Host example.com
  HostName server.provider.com
  User user1

Host example.it
  HostName server.provider.com
  User user2

Host example.es
  HostName server.provider.com
  User user3
```